# How To close Iframe in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have opened an i-frame in chrome extension but i don't know how to close it any idea how we can close the i-frame in chrome extension

Comment: document.getElementById('id-of-the-iframe').remove()

Answer (score 0):

You should check your background page console logs for errors.

To open this console logs screen:
https://images.app.goo.gl/h7y6W3ka3cnTu12R8

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer , First we have to provide an specific id to the iframe and than
do this
var iframe= document.getElementById( "someId" );
iframe.parentNode.removeChild( iframe);